# Why is get_values() needed in a membership test on a pandas DataFrame column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Given the following pandas DataFrame:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame([{'Campaign': 'Campaign X', 'Date': '24-09-2014', 'Spend': 1.34, 'Clicks': 241}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign Y', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 2.89, 'Clicks': 12}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign X', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 1.20, 'Clicks': 1}, {'Campaign': 'Campaign Z2', 'Date': '24-08-2014', 'Spend': 4.56, 'Clicks': 13}] )
```

[image]

If I fetch:

```
mydf['Campaign'][0]
```

I get:

```
'Campaign X'
```

One would expect then that `'Campaign X' in mydf['Campaign']` would return `True`. But it doesn't. And I find I need to append `get_values()` to make this membership test behave as I'd like. Why so?

Comment: use `mydf['Campaign'].isin(['Campaign X'])` to test for membership

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a Series as behaving more like an ordered dictionary than a list with this extra index.  Iteration and membership testing in a dictionary is over the *keys*, not the values: `x in somedict` is `x in somedict.keys()` not `x in somedict.values()`.

```
>>> mydf["Campaign"]
0     Campaign X
1     Campaign Y
2     Campaign X
3    Campaign Z2
Name: Campaign, dtype: object
>>> dict(mydf["Campaign"])
{0: 'Campaign X', 1: 'Campaign Y', 2: 'Campaign X', 3: 'Campaign Z2'}
>>> 2 in dict(mydf["Campaign"])
True
>>> "Campaign X" in dict(mydf["Campaign"])
False
>>> 2 in mydf["Campaign"]
True
>>> "Campaign X" in mydf["Campaign"]
False
```

and so we need

```
>>> "Campaign X" in mydf["Campaign"].values
True
>>> "Campaign X" in dict(mydf["Campaign"]).values()
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) to test for membership:

```
In [40]:

mydf['Campaign'].isin(['Campaign X'])
Out[40]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Campaign, dtype: bool
```

When you use `in` which fails:

```
In [39]:

'Campaign X' in mydf['Campaign']
Out[39]:
False
```

it's because the 'keys' are being checked which are the index labels/values:

```
In [41]:

mydf['Campaign']
Out[41]:
0     Campaign X
1     Campaign Y
2     Campaign X
3    Campaign Z2
Name: Campaign, dtype: object
```

Which is why your test fails, if you tested membership in the 'values' then it works:

```
In [44]:

'Campaign X' in mydf['Campaign'].values
Out[44]:
True
```

`values` attribute returns a np array:

```
In [45]:

mydf['Campaign'].values
Out[45]:
array(['Campaign X', 'Campaign Y', 'Campaign X', 'Campaign Z2'], dtype=object)
```

Additionally you can use the vectorised `str.contains` method to test for membership:

```
In [46]:

mydf['Campaign'].str.contains('Campaign X')
Out[46]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Campaign, dtype: bool
```